# Algorithm environment problem

Tags: errors, algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I am doing my master thesis and need to include an algorithm into my LaTeX code. I have been trying for hours now, but I still have several errors that always show up. It is my first time using the `algorithm` package, so help would be appreciated. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Resource Allocation Algorithm }
\label{alg:algorithm_sum}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State{Initialization of maximum number of iteration $I_{\text{max}}$, given $\mu^m$ and $\beta^m$ and obtain the intermediate solution for (opt. variables)} 
\If{ref. is satisfied} 
\State{Convergence =  true} 
\Return{opt. variables} 
\Else 
\State{update $\mu$ and $\beta$ according to ref. and $m=m+1$} 
\State{Convergence =  false} 
\EndIf
\Until{Convergence = true or $m=I_{\text{max}}$} 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you are loading both `algorithmic` and `algpseudocode` (variant of `algorithmicx`) which are not compatible.

The syntax you are using is the one of `algpseudocode` so don't load `algorithmic`. Moreover, you are using `\text` and forgot to load `amsmath`.

Finally, the `\Until` command has to be used to close a `\Repeat` statement which is missing in your code.

This is your modified MWE with `\Repeat` (move it to the right place in the algorithm):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Resource Allocation Algorithm }
\label{alg:algorithm_sum}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State{Initialization of maximum number of iteration $I_{\text{max}}$, given $\mu^m$ and $\beta^m$ and obtain the intermediate solution for (opt. variables)}
\Repeat
\If{ref. is satisfied}
\State{Convergence =  true}
\Return{opt. variables}
\Else
\State{update $\mu$ and $\beta$ according to ref. and $m=m+1$}
\State{Convergence =  false}
\EndIf
\Until{Convergence = true or $m=I_{\text{max}}$}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback, I will be more careful, it is a strange new environment for me :) And sometimes the errors are weird. This solved my problem!

Comment: @redpixel2511 You're welcome. Remember that you can accept one of the answers (the one which helped you most) to mark your question as solved. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to leave `algorithmic` and remove `algpseudocode` to eliminate incompatibility. But change the syntax a bit as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,algorithm,algorithmic}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Resource Allocation Algorithm }
\label{alg:algorithm_sum}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE{Initialization of maximum number of iteration $I_{\text{max}}$, given $\mu^m$ and $\beta^m$ and obtain the intermediate solution for (opt. variables)} 
\REPEAT
\IF{ref. is satisfied} 
\STATE{Convergence =  true} 
\RETURN{opt. variables} 
\ELSE 
\STATE{update $\mu$ and $\beta$ according to ref. and $m=m+1$} 
\STATE{Convergence =  false} 
\ENDIF
\UNTIL{Convergence = true or $m=I_{\text{max}}$} 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also that you may revise your algorithm, because `until` usually needs a `repeat` to close. You may change it as you wish.

Comment: `until` without a `repeat` doesn't look like pseodo-code...

Comment: Absolutely right!

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think I just forgot that line..